# How to restrict raw data to save in text file

Tags: java

I am developing a small application in Java. At certain point i need to save the object of my custom class to a text file for this i override `toString()` method in my custom class and then use `ObjectOutputStream` class to save object of my custom class to text file. Now everything works fine i.e my text file contains the text but along with that text it also contians some strange characters or raw data aswell. Following three lines contain major code for that

```
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
outputStream.writeObject(person);//person is the instance of my custom class
```

**Is there any way to restrict that raw data to be saved in my text file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ObjectOutputStream serializes objects that you pass to writeObject(). It doesn't write a text version of the object. If you want to write the value returned by toString() to a file, then open a file with something like a FileWriter, get the String by calling the toString() method, and then write it to the FileWriter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you should should maybe have a look at the XML Serialization libraries such as [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

The solution given above will only save the string representation of your object into a file (which could be what you want) but I guess that if you want to save an object into a file, it's probably to be able to access it afterwards.

Both JAXB and XStream provide methods to serialize/unserialize a Java object in XML. With XStream (maybe with JAXB also, I don't know), you can even serialize/unserialize your object(s) in JSON if you need something more compact.